# Sardine InputStream || HttpClient || SSL Certificate

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x, webdav, sardine

i am trying to download a file from a webdav server with the Sardine-Android Project Library. I have successfully achieved to iterate through the elements via the DavResource-List. 
I read through a lot of other questions but i'm a little bit confused:

1) `Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin("username", "password");
   sardine.enablePreemptiveAuthentication("webdav/");
   InputStream is = sardine.get("file");`

Although this instruction is written in the Usage Guide, it doesn't work.

ERROR Message: "Unknown Response".

2) Other People are using HttpClients with various SSL /TSL Certificates to access the WebDav Server. Now I have managed it to retrieve a Certificate via MAC Terminal, but I didn't understand how to use that to access the WebDav Server.

3) Do you any other library prehaps which makes possible to download a file from a WebDav Server or is it possible to write it myself (in terms of complicated complicatedness and required knowledge)

Thank you for any help in advance !